# Good practice for downcasting return type of inherited functions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, inheritance

I have got a `Matrix`-Class from which a `Vector`-Class is derived from and for extra functionality and better usage I've got a `Vector3`-Class which is derived from the `Vector` class. My problem is now that the `Vector`-class implements a function for instance `+normalizeVector:` which returns a new allocated `Vector`-instance. The subclass `Vector3` should inherit these two functions but an inheritance leads to the function-prototypes that return a `Vector`-instance and not a `Vector3`-instance. This is just how inheritance works but is there a good practice how to solve that problem? A naive solution is to create `Vector3` als a new class which subclasses `NSObject` but I want that `Vector`- and `Vector3`-instances can interact easily.

Here an code-example:

```
@interface Vector : NSObject {
....
}
+(Vector*) normalizeVector:(Vector*)v; //returns a new allocated Vector-instance
-(Vector*) normalize; //normalizes itself and returns itself
-(Vector*) otherFunction;
@end

@interface Vector3 : Vector {
}
-(Vector3*) specialFunction;
@end
```

usage of that code:

```
Vector3 *v3 = ...;
[[v3 normalize] specialFunction]; //Compiler gives me a warning because Vector has no specialFunction. Cast would help
[[Vector3 normalizeVector:v3] specialFunction]; //Compiler gives me a warning and during runtime it will crash because a `Vector` doesn't implement specialFunction
```

a cast to `Vector3` would help but is not nice to work with and that also fails with the static function `+normalizeVector:` because in that static function a `Vector`-instance is allocated and a pointer-cast doesn't help.

any ideas? or other approaches / other modeling ?

**edit:** Code for my static function normalizeVector which gets inherited by `Vector3`:

```
@implementation Vector
...
+(Vector*) normalizeVector:(Vector *)v
{
    unsigned int dim = vector_max(v.cols, v.rows);
    Vector *res = [[[Vector alloc]initAsColumnVectorWithDim:dim] autorelease];
    [Vector normalizeVector:v destination:res]; // this does only the logic: calc length and divide each component by the len and store at the vector passed to destination
    return res;
}
@end
```

Comment: Show the code for +normalizeVector:

Comment: @fakeAccount22: take a look at my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will notice that **-init** methods always return type id `-(id)init {..}` exactly becauase of this.

Also, instead of **[Vector alloc]** - as you have noticed you don't actually know what Class you are in at runtime (it could be a subclass), so instead just use `[self alloc]` where self is the current Class because you are in a Class method. So, if you do `[Vector3 normalizeVector:v]` self is **Vector3** and if you do `[Vector normalizeVector:v]` self is **Vector**.

Try adjusting your +normailzeVector: method to

```
+ (id)normalizeVector:(Vector *)v {
    unsigned int dim = vector_max(v.cols, v.rows);
    id res = [[[self alloc] initAsColumnVectorWithDim:dim] autorelease];
    [self normalizeVector:v destination:res];
    return res;
}
```

Just a note, `+ (id)normalizeVector:` is not a function and definitely not a static function. It is a class method, it just helps to get the terms right.

Comment: yes, that will help because I am directly overwriting the class method but using my code will also lead to casting and I know that `+normalizeVector:` called on a `Vector3`-instance returns a `Vector3` (due to overwriting with id-return-type). I think you are right relating to the id-return-type in init-methods. It is the same problem and only solved by returning the most general type.

Comment: thanks for the answer and edit. This helped a bit but I think there exist no solution without casting.

Comment: casting is sometimes a necessary evil. If you want strict type checking you must cast. If you don't want it, return type id. IMOA you are not helping yourself by having methods like - (Vector *)normalize; that modify the target in place and return a reference to self. Methods that 'modify in place' should not return a value. I know you probably like being able to chain method calls together but it isn't idiomatic Cocoa.

Comment: yep, you are right. I normally dont do that but I want to build a memory-efficient matrix, vector, ... classes because there will be a lot to calculate in relatively high frequencies (so I need data overwriting methods). I also need to calculate long linear equations and I want to code them in a way that the code is readable at the end: [[MyMatrix multiplyPost:[anotherMatrix invert]] sensorVector] .... (so I need self-returning methods - nicetohave feature)

Comment: Chaining method calls will offer no efficiency benefits, but whether or not you think it is more readable is your call.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would make normaliseVector an instance method. So instead of

Vector *newV = [Vector normalizeVector:v];

call

Vector *newV = [v normalizeVector];

Then you can produce a different  normalizeVector for Vector and Vector3

EDIT:
For [[v3 normalize] specialFunction]; there is a problem in that normalize can sometimes return an object that specialFunction does not work on - ie it only works if v3 is a Vector3. So in this case there is extra information you have so a cast would be needed or that Vector3 normailze differs from Vector's. In this case I would produce a cover method on Vector3 to call normalize] specialFunction] so that the cast is in Vector3 specific code.

Comment: but this doesn't solve the warning in `[[v3 normalize] specialFunction];` I think

Comment: @thomas: not for `-(Vector3*)normalize;` in `Vector3`.

Comment: thanks for your answer! relating to your edit: yes, I also thought to the same direction but my specialFunction can be arbitrary like crossProduct, dotProduct, multiplyScalar, ... I also tried to overwrite that function like Georg has suggested which calls the super function and does an addition cast but then there are two functions which only differs in the return-type which makes the compiler unhappy. I could also name that wrapper-function slightly different but then the User of my code has to guess which function to use.

Comment: The issue is what happens if special function is called on a Vector?